# Close Command and Update Command Don't Work With One Button

Tags: python, tkinter

So for this larger program I'm making I want it so when a user presses a button it closes the dialog windows and updates all the values the user input. Therefore, I have one button do these two things: update the values and close the program. However, trying to combine these two functions doesn't work as when I use both of them only the update() command is called, not the close command. Either works separately btw. Any way to fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

propDiameterInch = 10.5
propDiameterMetric = propDiameterInch*0.0254 

class Counter_program():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Test")
        
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="black", background="white")
        
        #default unit color
        unitColor = "slategrey"
        boxWidth = 5
        
        # Create some room around all the internal frames
        self.window['padx'] = 5
        self.window['pady'] = 5
        
        propeller_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, text="Propeller", relief=tk.RIDGE)
        propeller_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
        
        #propeller diameter
        propellerDiameter_label = ttk.Label(propeller_frame, text="Propeller Diameter")
        propellerDiameter_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W + tk.N +tk.S)
        
        propellerDiameter_Units = ttk.Label(propeller_frame, text="inches",foreground=unitColor)
        propellerDiameter_Units.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=tk.W)

        propellerDiameter_entry = ttk.Entry(propeller_frame, width=boxWidth)
        propellerDiameter_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)
        propellerDiameter_entry.insert(tk.END, "10")
        
        #now set all global variables from entries - update function
        def update():
            global propDiameter
            propDiameter = propellerDiameter_entry.get()
            
        # Finish button in the lower right corner
        #finish_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Submit Input", command = self.window.destroy)
        finish_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Submit Input", command=lambda:[update(),self.window.destroy])
        finish_button.grid(row=2, column=2)
        
# Create the entire GUI program
program = Counter_program()

# Start the GUI event loop
program.window.mainloop()

propDiameter
```

Comment: Just write a function to do what you want, and call that function from the command. Don't over-complicate it. Functions are much easier to understand and debug that lambdas.

Comment: Yeah, also thanks for that advice, will do so next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your using `lambda`, its safe to use `()` with the functions, so just change `finish_button` to:

```
finish_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Submit Input", command=lambda:[update(),self.window.destroy()])
```

Or you could make a new function that does both of this for you, like:

```
def both():
    update()
    self.window.destroy()

finish_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Submit Input", command=both)
```

**TIP:**
Also its not recommended to use `global` with OOP, so I recommend you change your code and use proper "methods" and `self` with OOP for a better experience.

Here is how I think your class should like:

```
class Counter_program():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Test")
        
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="black", background="white")
        
        #default unit color
        unitColor = "slategrey"
        boxWidth = 5
        
        # Create some room around all the internal frames
        self.window['padx'] = 5
        self.window['pady'] = 5
        
        self.propeller_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, text="Propeller", relief=tk.RIDGE)
        self.propeller_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
        
        #propeller diameter
        self.propellerDiameter_label = ttk.Label(self.propeller_frame, text="Propeller Diameter")
        self.propellerDiameter_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W + tk.N +tk.S)
        
        self.propellerDiameter_Units = ttk.Label(self.propeller_frame, text="inches",foreground=unitColor)
        self.propellerDiameter_Units.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=tk.W)

        self.propellerDiameter_entry = ttk.Entry(self.propeller_frame, width=boxWidth)
        self.propellerDiameter_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)
        self.propellerDiameter_entry.insert(tk.END, "10")
        
        # Finish button in the lower right corner
        #finish_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Submit Input", command = self.window.destroy)
        self.finish_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Submit Input", command=self.both)
        self.finish_button.grid(row=2, column=2)
        
    def update(self):
        self.propDiameter = self.propellerDiameter_entry.get()

    def both(self):
        self.update()
        self.window.destroy()
```

Hope this solved the issue, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah that works. Wow, I was expecting this to be a lot more complicated, will know for next time that things like that cause a big difference. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SuzukiPro Would appreciate marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: My bad didn't know how to do it had to look it up.